# How to export functions from a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

The basic structure of my hook:

```js
const useMyHook = () => {
  const func1 = (): boolean => { ... }
  const func2 = (type: "type1" | "type2"): boolean => { ... }
  const func3 = (): boolean => { ... }

  return {
    func1, func2, func3
  }
}

export default useMyHook
```

I'm currently using it like this, **which works in dev**, but breaks my build.

```
import useMyHook from "../hooks/useMyHook";

const { func1 } = useMyHook()

const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isValid = func1();

  if (isValid) {
  // do more things
  }
}

return (
  <form>...</form>
)
```

When running `yarn build`, I am faced with this error:

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {func1, func2, func3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

My attempt at solving this was to export my custom hook functions in an array, as the error seemed to suggest.

```js
  return [
    func1, func2, func3
  ]
```

And using it like this:

```js
  const [ func1 ] = useMyHook();
  const isValid = func1();
```

TypeScript is not happy with this:

```
An argument for 'type' was not provided.
```

But this is confusing, because `func1` does not accept a `type` argument as `func2` does.

### Questions

1. Is there some way I work around this build-time error and export the `{ }` of functions? This feels like the cleanest approach.
2. If there is no way to achieve **1**, how can I properly use the exported array of functions without my types being misread?

Comment: Does your hook use other hooks (from react)? If no, then it's not a hook, just an ordinary function.

Comment: Please post your complete code. You have a top-level `return` statement outside of any function. Where does your component start and where does it end?

Comment: "*object with keys {isValidateCompanyInfo, isValidateEligibilityInfo, isValidateCompliance, isValidateBenefitInfo}*" - this seems completely unrelated to the code you posted. Please provide a [mcve]. Especially since "*Objects are not valid as a React child*" means you're rendering something wrong in JSX, but the only JSX code you posted is the incomplete `<form>...</form>`, and again, it has nothing to do with your hook.

Comment: @Bergi Apologies. I tried to simplify my question and some of the actual code had leaked through. The error output has been adjusted.

Comment: So you are somewhere returning the hook results in the render section.

Comment: Btw, one does not "export" things from a function, one only *returns* values.

Comment: it works in DEV, but React.Strict mode is applied in PROD mode, that's why its not working in PROD

Comment: @Bergi My hook does use other hooks from React.

Comment: Add your render method, that will be helpful, and your second code snippet doesn't seem like a valid react component

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I included the `return ()` (render function) in my question, as I'm not using a class-based component. The render is just a form with a submit button.

Comment: your hooks are fine, it has nothing to do with error you encountering